# Filter to only pass specific headers by Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

For example here is a list of headers set by the frontend project and send all by default

```
* accept: application/json
* accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
* accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;
* authorization: xxxx
* cache-control: no-cache
* content-type: application/json
* pragma: no-cache
* referer: xxx
* sec-fetch-dest: empty
* sec-fetch-mode: cors
* sec-fetch-site: same-origin
* x-request-id: xxx-xxx-xxx
```

I have an Nginx location block (AWS Cloudfront) that for this specific API endpoint, I want to only pass specific headers (only passing 'authorization' and 'x-request-id') to the upstream, how I can configure the proxy_set_header directive?

```
location /some/special/api/ {
    resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=60s;
    proxy_pass         https://some.special.com/api/;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    client_max_body_size       50m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout      600;
    proxy_send_timeout         600;
    proxy_read_timeout         600;
    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set [`proxy_pass_request_headers off;`](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header) to disable sending all request headers upstream, and then use [`proxy_set_header <header>;`](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header) for each header that you explicitly want to pass.

For example, you could add:

```
proxy_pass_request_headers off;
proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $http_x_request_id;
```

Comment: thanks, but how I can set $http_x_request_id, etc for each request? Are they automatically assigned like $http_x_request_id = x-request-id?

Comment: That's what [those variables](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) are for